# Redshift SQL null is missing in aggregator?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have table with following columns & rows

```
Country           campaign events                       events
DE      RTEST [FB] ACQ Buyer - NDPA - Marketplace (REV - Retention - $15 - July) v1 10000

HK                another campaign                      20000
_null_            no campaign                           30000
```

Now if I run the following query

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE mkt_campaign != 'RTEST
>   [FB] ACQ Buyer - NDPA - Marketplace (REV - Retention - $15 - July) v1'

I should get 50000 as my output, but getting only 20000.

Questions
1. Is my filter condition is correct or those braces are any meta character or escape sequence etc.
2. why null row is not considered in count aggregation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These NULL handling behaviors are defined by the ANSI SQL standard.

Your "not equal" `!=` filter implicitly excludes null values because they cannot be compared. You would need to add `OR mkt_campaign IS NULL` to include them.

Also note that aggregate functions (*exlcuding* `COUNT(*)`) remove NULL values http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/gotchasqlaggregatefunctionsandnull/1947/